# Convert string to jquery object and extract data from it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

HTML

```
<span id = 'testlabel'></span>
```

JS

```
var test = '<tr style="display:none" class="projinfo">test<br/>test</tr>' +   
'<tr><td column="Type"><b>Project</b></td><tr>';

 var dom = $(test).filter('.projinfo');

 var content = dom.length > 0 ? dom[0].innerHTML:'No data';

$('#testlabel').text('Content is ' + content);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsiry01/g4fd5/6/)

In Chrome, I am expecting the result of my jsfiddle to be

"Content is test
test"

instead I get

Content is

What am I missing here ?

In IE 9 I am getting the correct result ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the HTML jQuery is creating isn't being evaluated the same on Chrome (taking your word that it works in IE). This is because the `<tr>` doesn't have a `<td>` inside it. If you change your content to the following:

```
var test = '<tr style="display:none" class="projinfo"><td>test</td></tr>' +   
'<tr><td column="Type"><b>Project</b></td><tr>';

 var dom = $(test).filter('.projinfo').find('td');

 var content = dom.length > 0 ? dom[0].innerHTML:'No data';

$('#testlabel').text('Content is ' + content);
```

It'll work properly:

```
Content is test
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4fd5/8/)